# What plane can the keep acquired via the Throne card from the Deck of Many Things be on?

Tags: dnd-5e, planes, magic-items

From the [Deck of Many Things](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/deck-of-many-things) (DMG, p. 164):

> ***Throne.*** You gain proficiency in the Persuasion skill, and you double your proficiency bonus on checks made with that skill. In addition, you gain rightful ownership of a small keep **somewhere in *the world***. However, the keep is currently in the hands of monsters, which you must clear out before you can claim the keep as yours.

It says "somewhere in *the world*"; does this mean on the Material Plane, or could it potentially be on any plane of existence? I know it's left intentionally vague to allow the DM more flexibility, but I wondered if "the world" at least implies the Material Plane...

Comment: @SpacyRicochet any time you feel the need to preface a comment with "not an answer, but..." it's a pretty good bet what you're posting is a comment answer.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer Sure, but the moment that would've been made as a real answer, people would've been banging the 'not-RAW, go home' drum. Hence, not an answer. Also, did my previous comment get deleted entirely? Not sure how I feel about that (especially since I can't find a way to check when and why it happened.)

Comment: @SpacyRicochet [Comments get deleted all the time.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1174/8610) Best not to get too attached to them. The site isn't resistant to answers that go beyond the rules, but the site prefers answers that address the rules first, even if that means an answer begins with *The rules don't say, but in my campaigns…* or whatever.

Comment: @SpacyRicochet I deleted it via mod powers because answers may not be posted in the comment section, regardless of the reason to not want to post them in the answer section. It’s either in the answer section or not at all. See [this FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/321) for more details. I didn’t say anything at the time because someone had already explained the problem for me. (Also, Hey I Can Chan’s advice is good.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Thanks for the explanation. And Hey I can Chan's advice is indeed very good. Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules don't specify this. I have run the Throne a couple of times, and seen it run by other DMs. A couple of things that seem implicit in the card:

- You know where your keep is.
- You know how to get there.

Those seem to suggest that it's somewhere you *can* go with reasonable efforts: it's not a very favourable card if just getting to the keep costs more than its value. So I'd expect to put it somewhere relevant to the campaign, that the characters can reach, and where having a base would be advantageous.

- For a character planning their retirement, it might be somewhere fairly safe.
- For a character who wants to start adventuring on other planes, it might indeed be on another plane, but there would be a reliable way of getting there.
- For a character who already has connections to another plane - which might be as simple as a wizard who concentrates on fire magic - it might have a gateway to that plane.

Overall, the Deck of Many Things is a very dangerous item, so it's worth customising the rewards, if there are any, to the character who risked it.